# TensorFlow Mask_RCNN InvalidArgumentError

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-segmentation

In Google Colab. Trying to set up and run an instance segmentation with the Mask_RCNN from https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN. Using the following package versions

```
!pip install h5py==2.10.0
!pip install tensorflow==1.15
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
!pip install keras==2.1.6
```

This is the starting code block.

```
import os
import sys
import random
import math
import re
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Root directory of the project
ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath("../../")

# Import Mask RCNN
sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR)  # To find local version of the library
from mrcnn.config import Config
from mrcnn import utils
import mrcnn.model as modellib
from mrcnn import visualize
from mrcnn.model import log

%matplotlib inline 

# Directory to save logs and trained model
MODEL_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "logs")

# Local path to trained weights file
COCO_MODEL_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
# Download COCO trained weights from Releases if needed
if not os.path.exists(COCO_MODEL_PATH):
    utils.download_trained_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH)
```

Then I set up the configurations as such:

```
> Configurations:
> BACKBONE                       resnet101 
> BACKBONE_STRIDES               [4, 8, 16, 32, 64] 
> BATCH_SIZE                     1 
> BBOX_STD_DEV                   [0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2] 
> COMPUTE_BACKBONE_SHAPE         None
> DETECTION_MAX_INSTANCES        100 
> DETECTION_MIN_CONFIDENCE       0.7
> DETECTION_NMS_THRESHOLD        0.3 
> FPN_CLASSIF_FC_LAYERS_SIZE     1024
> GPU_COUNT                      1 
> GRADIENT_CLIP_NORM             5.0
> IMAGES_PER_GPU                 1 
> IMAGE_CHANNEL_COUNT            3
> IMAGE_MAX_DIM                  1024 
> IMAGE_META_SIZE                14
> IMAGE_MIN_DIM                  1024 
> IMAGE_MIN_SCALE                0
> IMAGE_RESIZE_MODE              square 
> IMAGE_SHAPE                    [1024 1024    3] 
> LEARNING_MOMENTUM              0.9 
> LEARNING_RATE                  0.001 
> LOSS_WEIGHTS                   {'rpn_class_loss': 1.0, 'rpn_bbox_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_class_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_bbox_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_mask_loss': 1.0} 
> MASK_POOL_SIZE                 14 
> MASK_SHAPE                     [28, 28] 
> MAX_GT_INSTANCES               100 
> MEAN_PIXEL                     [123.7 116.8 103.9] 
> MINI_MASK_SHAPE                (56, 56) 
> NAME                           shapes 
> NUM_CLASSES                    2 
> POOL_SIZE                      7 
> POST_NMS_ROIS_INFERENCE        1000 
> POST_NMS_ROIS_TRAINING         2000 
> PRE_NMS_LIMIT                  6000 
> ROI_POSITIVE_RATIO             0.33 
> RPN_ANCHOR_RATIOS              [0.5, 1, 2]
> RPN_ANCHOR_SCALES              (64, 128, 256, 512) 
> RPN_ANCHOR_STRIDE              1 
> RPN_BBOX_STD_DEV               [0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2] 
> RPN_NMS_THRESHOLD              0.7
> RPN_TRAIN_ANCHORS_PER_IMAGE    256 
> STEPS_PER_EPOCH                25
> TOP_DOWN_PYRAMID_SIZE          256
> TRAIN_BN                       False 
> TRAIN_ROIS_PER_IMAGE           16
> USE_MINI_MASK                  True
> USE_RPN_ROIS                   True
> VALIDATION_STEPS               5 
> WEIGHT_DECAY                   0.0001
```

When I run the following to train the model:

```
# Create model object in inference mode.
model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir=MODEL_DIR, config=config)

# Load weights trained on MS-COCO
model.load_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH, by_name=True)
```

I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
 
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)    
   1606 try:
-> 1607     c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)    
   1608   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
 
InvalidArgumentError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 8 and 324. Shapes are [1024,8] and [1024,324]. for 'Assign_682' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [1024,8], [1024,324].
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
```

I don't know what objects the "shapes" refer to, so I don't know what I'm supposed to fix.

Comment: My first guess is that the number of classes is not correct. Does the model you're trying to load have only 2 outputs? Is this relevant? https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/363

Comment: You may find this notebook useful regarding your whole training pipeline. https://www.kaggle.com/ipythonx/keras-global-wheat-detection-with-mask-rcnn

Comment: @jhso maybe it is the number of classes. I have only the background and then polygons which are similar in shape that are my areas of interest in my images, so I thought there would be only 2 classes. Thanks for suggesting that G.H. issue thread. It may be useful.

Comment: @M.Innat thanks for that suggestion. I will give it a look!